Correlation coefficient of X/Z and Y/Z
Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with correlation coefficient $r_{x,y} \neq 0$. Let $Z$ another random variable, independent of $Y$ and $X$.
Define $W \equiv \frac{X}{Z}$ and $T \equiv \frac{Y}{Z}$.
What is the correlation coefficient of $W$ and $T$ in terms of $r_{x,y}$?
My first approach was to try assuming $EX = EY = EZ= 0$. Then:
$$r_{w,t} = \frac{E(\frac{X}{Z} \frac{Y}{Z})}{\sqrt{V(\frac{X}{Z}) V(\frac{Y}{Z})}}$$
For the denominator we have this property
$\mathrm{Var}(XY)=E(X)^2 \mathrm{Var}(Y)+E(Y)^2 \mathrm{Var}(X)+\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)$
In this context this equals to $V(X/Z) = V(X)V(1/Z)$
So:
$$r_{w,t} = \frac{E(\frac{X}{Z} \frac{Y}{Z})}{\sqrt{V(X)V(1/Z)V(Y)V(1/Z)}}$$
Since $V(\cdot) = E(\cdot^2)$ in this context, we obtain:
$$r_{w,t} = \frac{E(\frac{1}{Z^2}) E(XY)}{\sqrt{V(X)V(Y) E(\frac{1}{Z^2})^2}}$$
Simplyfing:
$$r_{w,t} = \frac{E(XY)}{\sqrt{V(X)V(Y)}} \equiv r_{x,y}$$
If I try to remove the assumptions of all expectations equal to zero, the algebra is considerably cumbersome. Does this holds por $EX, EY, EZ \neq 0$?

The answer is that unless the $(X,Y)$ distribution is supported on a line through the origin (whence $r_{X,Y}$ is $0$ or $\pm 1$), and the only information you have about the variables is $r_{X,Y},$ the correlation of $(X/Z,Y/Z)$ could be any number in the interval $(-1,1).$ To see why, note that division by $Z$ replaces each point in the $(X,Y)$ scatterplot by a measure supported on the line connecting $(0,0)$ and $(X,Y):$ draw some pictures for small finite datasets and you'll get the idea.
